# Spring Integration throwing NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I try to build a simple Spring Integration folder for a data import. But the process throws `NoSuchFileException` when processing the last file.
I am using Spring 5.0.5 (and in this demo Spring Boot 2.0.1)

**configuration**:

```
<bean id="dataImporter" class="com.example.demo.DataImporter" />

<bean id="XMLFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter" >
    <constructor-arg value="*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="XMLFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileListFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="filter" ref="XMLFileListFilter" />
    <property name="preventDuplicates" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="importFileComparator" class="com.example.demo.ImportFileComparator" />

<!--Input channel-->
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="FilesInChannel"
        directory="file:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/SI-Failing"
        filter="XMLFilter"
        auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!--Output channel-->
<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="FilesOutChannel"
    default-output-channel="FilesOutSuccessChannel" >
    <int:recipient channel="FilesOutFailureChannel" selector-expression="headers.containsKey('IMPORT_FAILURE')" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<!--Success / Failure channel-->
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="FilesOutSuccessChannel"
    directory="file:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/SI-Failing/success/" delete-source-files="true"
    filename-generator-expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss').format(new java.util.Date()) + '_' + payload.name"/>
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="FilesOutFailureChannel"
    directory="file:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/SI-Failing/error" delete-source-files="true"
    filename-generator-expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss').format(new java.util.Date()) + '_' + payload.name"/>

<!--Verheiratung zwischen Importer, Input und Output-->
<int:service-activator
    ref="dataImporter"
    input-channel="FilesInChannel"
    output-channel="FilesOutChannel" />
```

This is the import handler:

```
public class DataImporter {

    public Message<File> handleFileImport(Message<File> message) {
        final File file = message.getPayload();
        System.out.println("Processing file " + file);
        return message;
    }
}
```

And when putting 3 XML files into the folder, this log message will generated:

```
2018-05-09 13:47:34.989  INFO 6888 --- [ask-scheduler-5] 

o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_1.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_1.xml, id=29b41c2e-3302-ca26-93a5-423f6f57fd4d, file_name=typeA_1.xml, file_relativePath=typeA_1.xml, timestamp=1525866454989}]]
Processing file C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_1.xml
2018-05-09 13:47:35.986  INFO 6888 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml, id=4fe71062-12b0-3649-56de-8c432ae2c6e4, file_name=typeA_2.xml, file_relativePath=typeA_2.xml, timestamp=1525866455986}]]
Processing file C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml
2018-05-09 13:47:35.991 ERROR 6888 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file; nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml, id=4fe71062-12b0-3649-56de-8c432ae2c6e4, file_name=typeA_2.xml, file_relativePath=typeA_2.xml, timestamp=1525866455986}]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:590)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:372)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\fischer\Desktop\SI-Failing\typeA_2.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:318)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.rename(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleFileMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:626)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:559)
    ... 55 more
```

It seems that spring tries to fetch a file which itself already carried into the `success` folder, therefore failing with `NoSuchFileException` ...
What am I doing wrong?

If needed I can provide a Sping Boot demo application: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fwr9qi84c03u85/demo.7z?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `<property name="preventDuplicates" value="false" />`.

This way the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` will be able to poll the same file again on next polling cycle. However I see that it's OK since you have a `delete-source-files="true"` on both `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`. So, the `preventDuplicates` option is not so important.

That's one point to think. Another one and which I think is a strong culprit is this: `fixed-rate="1000"`. When you process a file some long time, the scheduler may start a new polling task and therefore may pick up the same file since you haven't reached `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` for deletion. Consider to switch to the `fixed-delay="1000"` instead.

**UPDATE**

The solution for you is like this:

```
  <bean id="XMLFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter" >
    <constructor-arg value="*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="acceptOnceFileListFilter"
      class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="foo"/>
</bean>

<bean id="XMLFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="XMLFileListFilter"/>
            <ref bean="acceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Pay attention to the `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. As I said in one comment below, it is good one do not pass the same file, but it can track the modifications of the same file. So, you can place a new version of the same file to the directory and as long as its timestamp is fresh, the file is going to be picked up by the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: Hmm as I read here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/130289-how-to-poller-to-wait-for-first-poll-to-complete the `fixed-delay` vs `fixed-rate` should not matter - one poll will we done after another (if this is true what I read there). Also, I just tested it with `fixed-delay` but no luck - the same behavior persists. Also I need to import duplicates as it might happen that a same-named file will be thrown in as some time before (but with new content). Do you maybe have more suggestions?

Comment: Well, there is something else. Maybe thread shifting. But `fixed-delay` has to be a solution for you, if you don't send messages in downstream to some other threads. In other words your solution should be single-threaded do not collide with the same file twice at the same time

Comment: Make it like `fixed-delay="10000"` - just to be sure that it works well

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, I seem to miss something else ... If you have spare time, I'd be interested in the result of the demo application I provided: Throw in like 5 XML files (with like no content, mine have a single letter in them) and see if it crashes on like third or forth file as it does for me

Comment: Would you mind to share the project via GitHub, so I can poll it locally, run and debug? Please, share there some README to let me to know how to reproduce. As far as I see your code here, the only problem is `fixed-delay` for that `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: As I had this problem on work, I now tried my own sample at home - with luck. No error what so ever (even with 1000er `-rate`). I start to believe that somehow it might be my system causing whatever kind of troubles. I didn't even tried sth like rebooting the PC, so maybe when I come back everything works fine out of nowhere... I keep you posted, and if the problem persists I'll try upping a demo to github for you

Comment: Also you should keep in mind that when you have several app instances watching the same directory you really may end up with similar problem.

Comment: BTW, there is a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which is based on the the `file.lastModified()`. So, even if file with the same name will appear in the directory, it is treated as a new one. I mean that you need to add this into your `XMLFilter`.

Comment: I reproduced it now, try it here: https://github.com/baerus/demo.git It's a bit different than before as I got closer to the real scenario, which is using a comparator and the `scan-each-poll="true"` flag. Exception will be thrown by comparator while reading a file which already got moved by Spring (I guess). A readme is attached. I am unfamiliar with git(hub) so if not all info is there, say a word. Thanks!

Comment: Listen, but you still use there `fixed-rate="1000"`. I told you to replace that with the `fixed-delay`. Why do we return to the original problem?

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `scan-each-poll="true"` for this type of `Comparator` or you shouldn't delete files in the end. The problem with your  `Comparator` that it reads a content of the file to compare on the next poll, while it tries to do that against already deleted file.

Comment: Would be better if something what writes files would place that `type` into the file name to let you to avoid reading from the comparator.

Comment: Yeah I assumed similar. I need to use `scan-each-poll` as I need to maintain a certain priority order. And as I could always throw in a new file, which might be of higher priority (which I can only know by looking into the file), at any time while ongoing process, this flag is crucial. The files will actually come from another process which I have no control of. This process puts the files inside the folder, with no possibility to change the content nor the name. Seems like I have to find a way of some preprocessing before polling? Is something like that possible with Spring Integration?

Comment: Well, you can do that yourself: poll files, read them, renames with the type and put them back to the folder. And do that with the separate poller. Then change your comparator do not look into the content of the file.

Comment: Another option is to process all the polled files in one polling task - `max-messages-per-poll="-1"`

Comment: I am not sure if I got the second option right, but it is crucial that after processing one file, I need to rescan all files which are then available, as there might be a shifting as when new files arrived, with maybe higher priority. I am sure it will work using a second poller (and with poller you mean another input/output channel configuration?) but it seems like a bit of ... unhandy coding for this task. Is this really the simplest solution to "I have files with priority (inside the file)" and need to process one after another"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170813/discussion-between-baerus-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.